# Is there a way to use shutil to copy a file when you don’t know the whole file name?

Tags: python, shutil, python-os

I am trying to use shutil.copy to copy files that I don’t know the whole name for. The names typically are 11_11_2023_functional. The date changes each for each file but they are in separate folders. How can I copy the file based on the fact that it says ‘functional’ in the name of it?

I was using the basic shutil.copy command and it works. I tried using a variable in the name but it won’t work because I am unaware of the date on the file name.

Comment: `files = glob.glob("*_functional")` etc. if you're feeling motivated write a regex

Comment: Use `glob.glob()` to crawl through directory trees, look for filenames that fit your needs with `os.path`-function you can check, creation time, size, etc. when you have identified the correct file, copy it with`shutil.copy`

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
import shutil
files = glob.glob("/*/*_functional")
for file in files:
    shutil.copy(...)
```

`/*/` for folder and `*_functional` for file name.